# How can one reorder cells in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dask

I'm trying to reorder cells in a jupyter notebook.  I've read other posts that suggest that the "edit" menu should have "move cell up" and "move cell down" menu items, but it doesn't.

The cell I want to move is selected.

Jupyter was installed less than a month ago using pip.  I'm using Chrome under Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: They normally have little arrows or hide 'em in a 3-dot menu at the top right of the individual cell to shuffle 'em, assuming you're using a normal notebook!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not seeing the dots or arrows in the upper right corner of the cell though.

Comment: I just reset to the default theme and now I can see move items in the edit menu.  I really need a dark background theme to be able to see what I'm doing though.

Comment: As a general hack, sometimes you can just invert the colors to get a dark theme, but it can be ugly or not be sensible system-wide.

Comment: The root of my problem seems to be that the controls aren't visible if one's browser is set to use the dask theme -- an essential accessibility mode for me.

Comment: that could be a bug - added `dask` tag so the coiled folks might see it!